# Function calculating newTime - oldTIme to add points to a var seems to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

- A div called "tm" in here a timer is ticking, e.g. 00:03:34
  (hh:mm:ss)
- I have a function called `setScore();` which is called
  regular
- I have the following vars:

1: `var pointsAvailable = 40;`

2: `var oldTime = 00:00:00;`

Now I want to ad 10 points to pointsAvailable every time the function is called within 2 seconds. If it's longer, pointsAvailable must be set back to 40. Since the timer keeps on ticking, oldTime (which is the starting time) should be replaced by newTime (every time the function has run).

I came up with the following code:

```
var pointsAvailable = 40; //start value
var oldTime = 00:00:00; //start value

function setScore() {
    var newTime = document.getElementById('tm').innerHTML; //get the time from div: 'tm' e.g. 00:00:02
    var findTime = (newTime - oldTime); //calculate the time in between e.g. 00:00:02 - 00:00:00 = 2

    if (findTime < 3) { //is it smaller then 3?
        pointsAvailable += 10; //add 10 to the pointsAvailable
    } else { //is it 3 or bigger?
        pointsAvailable = 40; //set it back to 40
    }
    oldTime = newTime; //replace oldTime with newTime, so newTime becomes oldTime
}
```

But it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,
Maurice

Comment: what does your console say to this?

Comment: Does `var oldTime = 00:00:00;` not give you an error in your console?

Comment: Why are you subtracting two strings? You don't have any operations to convert the time into a number, so there is no way that subtraction will do what you want.

Comment: agh of course it's still a string :S thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use JavaScript's built-in Date object.  When you create a new Date, it defaults to the current date and time; you can use this to get a time span:

```
js> d = new Date()
Sat Feb 11 2012 11:16:49 GMT-0800 (PST)
js> e = new Date()
Sat Feb 11 2012 11:16:56 GMT-0800 (PST)
js> e - d
7077
js>
```

So create a start date when you want to start your "timer" running, then create another one when you want it to stop.  Subtracting the latter from the former will give you the time difference (in milliseconds).

Hope that helps!